# Почему объект FirebaseAuth не передаётся через intent?

Tags: java, android, firebase

В моём приложении есть 2 **Activity**: **MainActivity** и **AppActivity**.
На **MainActivity** у меня происходит авторизация **FirebaseAuth** для **FirebaseUser**. А на **AppActivity** я хотел бы реализовать `FirebaseAuth.signout()`. Для этого я хочу передать **FirebaseUser** и **FirebaseAuth** из **MainActivity** в **AppActivity**:

```java
public void moveToAppActivity(FirebaseUser user, FirebaseAuth auth) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AppActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("user", user);
    intent.putExtra("auth", auth);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему объект **FirebaseUser** прекрасно передаётся в **AppActivity**, а строка:

```
intent.putExtra("auth", auth);
```

Где **auth** это объект **FirebaseAuth** уже в IDE подсвечивает **ошибку**:

```
Cannot resolve method 'putExtra(java.lang.String, com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Андроиде все данные между разными активити передаются в специальном контейнере [Parcel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel). В этот контейнер можно складывать только определнные типы данных. Один из таких типов — `Parcelable`.

В вашем конкретном случае [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) имплементирует интерфейс `Parcelable`, а [FirebaseAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth) — нет, поэтому передать его в extras нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, если авторизация происходит на 1м Activity, то на 2й Activity не нужно передавать ни FirebaseAuth, ни FirebaseUser, так как из 2го Activity к ним можно легко получить доступ как:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signout();
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
```

Как оказалось всё очень просто.